# Cross product between list of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

let's say i have 2 lists like below:

```
list1=[[1],[2],[3]]
list2=[[4],[5]]
```

What i would like to do is cross product between the list items in these two lists.In this example the result would be :

```
    result_list=[[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5],[3,4],[3,5]]
```

How could this be done using python ? i have searched online for a bit but i can't find a solution and i've been stuck.Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can try `itertools.product`

```py
from itertools import product
list1=[[1],[2],[3]]
list2=[[4],[5]]

output = [[x[0][0], x[1][0]] for x in product(list1, list2)]

print(output)
```

```
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

That is cartesian product, but as you have 2-level lists as input, you need a little trick to get the result

- flatten the result after product

  ```
  from itertools import product, chain
  res = [list(chain(*r)) for r in product(list1, list2)]
  ```
- flatten the input list before product

  ```
  res = list(product(chain(*list1), chain(*list2)))
  ```

---

If you have 1-level list, it's just

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5]
res = list(product(list1, list2))
print(res)  # [(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=[[1],[2],[3]]
list2=[[4],[5]]
a =[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        a.append([i[0],j[0]])
print(a)
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *how* this code helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

From itertools, `product` will produce the required pairings but the output will be tuples of on-item lists.  You can use chain.from_iterable to combine those lists and map the result to lists efficiently:

```
from itertools import product,chain
result_list = [*map(list,map(chain.from_iterable,product(list1,list2)))]

[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5]]
```